# Emit before and after every retry

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

1. I have an epic, that listens for a certain action.
2. Once it gets the action, it should do a `ajax.post`
3. Branch

   - If status code is good, then emit `YES`
   - If status bad, then emit `pre`, wait 1s, emit `post`

I am struggling mightily with the last bullet, here is my code in a playground - https://rxviz.com/v/WJxGMl4O

Here is my pipeline part:

```
action$.pipe(
    flatMap(action =>
        defer(() => ajax.post('foo foo foo')).pipe(
            tap(res => console.log('succeeded:', res)),
            mapTo('YES'),
            retryWhen(error$ =>
                error$.pipe(
                    tap(error => console.log('got error:', error)),
                    merge(of('pre')), // this isnt emiting
                    delay(1000),
                    merge(of('post')) // this isnt emitting
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I'm confused on what you're after here. can you try to explain a bit more. like where in this chain should the actual retry occur? and how often / many times?

Comment: Thanks @bryan60 I'm struggling with this for hours. If you go to the playgorund, and click "visualize" you will see this - https://i.imgur.com/tVUV5P0.png - however what I want to see is this:

Comment: oops @bryan60 here's the 2nd screenshot https://i.imgur.com/c9VaWsd.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want by using `catchError` instead of `retryWhen` because `retryWhen` only reacts to `next` notifications but won't propagate them further. With `catchError` you get also the source Observable which you can return and thus re-subscribe. `concat` subscribes to all its source one after another only after the previous one completed so it'll first send the two messages `pre` and `post` and after that retry.

```
action$.pipe(
    filter(action => action === 'hi'),
    mergeMap(action =>
        defer(() => resolveAfter(3)).pipe(
            tap(res => console.log('succeeded:', res)),
            mapTo('YES'),
            catchError((error, source$) => {
                console.log('retrying, got error:', error);
                return staticConcat(
                    of('pre'),
                    of('post').pipe(delay(1000)),
                    source$,
                );
           }),
        )
    ),
    //take(4)
)
```

Your updated demo: https://rxviz.com/v/A8D7BzyJ

Comment: Oh wow that is so cool. Thank you!! How did you know that `retryWhen` will not propgate them? I'm trying to learn how to read the docs so I could have figured this out without asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

First, I created 2 custom operators, one that will handle 'pre' & 'post'(`skipValidation`) and one that will handle the logic(`useValidation`).

```js
const skipValidation = src => of(src).pipe(
  concatMap(
    v => of('post').pipe(
     startWith('pre'),
     delay(1000),
    ),
  ),
);
```

What's important to notice in the snippet below is `action$.next({ skip: true })`. With that, we are emitting new values that will go through the **iif operator** so that we can emit 'pre' & 'post';

```js
const useValidation = src => of(src).pipe(
 filter(action => action === 'hi'),
    mergeMap(action =>
        defer(() => resolveAfter(3)).pipe(
            tap(res => console.log('succeeded:', res)),
            mapTo('YES'),
            delay(1000),
            retryWhen(error$ =>
                error$.pipe(
                        tap(error => { console.log('retrying, got error:', error); action$.next({ skip: true })}),
                        delay(1000),
                )
            )
        )
      )
);
```

```js
action$.pipe(
    tap(v => console.log('v', v)), // Every emitted value will go through the `iif ` operator
    mergeMap(v => iif(() => typeof v === 'object' && v.skip, skipValidation(v), useValidation(v))),
)
```

[Here is your updated demo](https://rxviz.com/v/5o1xp3D8).

Comment: Thank you for showing this! I wanted to learn custom operators, and seeing with respect to a need I had, makes it so easy to understand!

Comment: I’m glad it was useful. Best of luck!